# How expiration field values for documents from a "time to live" (TTL) is calculated in Solr?

Tags: solr, solr4

I went through the Java-doc @ [DocExpirationUpdateProcessorFactory](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/5_5_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/update/processor/DocExpirationUpdateProcessorFactory.html)  . It says :

> The DocExpirationUpdateProcessorFactory provides two features related
>   to the "expiration" of documents which can be used individually, or in
>   combination:
>
> - Computing expiration field values for documents from a "time to live"    (TTL)
> - Periodically delete documents from the index based on an       expiration field

**But it didn't specify how expirationField values are calculated from ttl field.**

**Anybody can help to understand how its calculated?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `ttlFieldName` - Name of a field this process should look for in each document processed, defaulting to `_ttl_`. If the specified field name exists in a document, the document field value will be *parsed as a Date Math Expression relative to NOW* and the result will be added to the document using the `expirationFieldName`.

This means that you can use terms like `+2 HOURS` in the `_ttl_` field to make the document expire in two hours from when it was indexed. This date value will then be stored in the `expirationFieldName` field.

From [Cloudera's documentation about the introduction of the feature](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Solr-TTL-Auto-Purging-Solr-Documents-Ranger-Audits/ta-p/247920):

> Current Time is: `2016-10-26 20:14:00`
>
> `_ttl_` is defined as: +2HOURS
>
> This will result in an expiration value of `2016-10-26 22:14:00`

There are [also more examples in Lucidworks description of the feature](https://lucidworks.com/post/document-expiration/):

```
{ "id"             : "live_2_minutes_b",
  "time_to_live_s" : "+120SECONDS"            
},
```